# how to style react to be responsive across screen sizes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive

I am trying to style react movie search app to be responsive across devices, like when I type something on the search bar, I wish to see my react form changing size and moving up to the top, making way for the my card, but instead it creates a mess. I tried using props and passed style with logic, but it doesn't include all screen sizes

[image]

What I wanted was to have the hard in the middle with the search being at top and button display to none, but the bigger issue u how they turn out as the screen decrease overflow beyond the screen size

googled, surprisingly, nobody is talking about this

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
//import "./movieForm.css";

export default function ({
  movieName,
  inputStyle,
  buttonStyle,
  containerStyle,
  h1Style,
}) {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState("");
  const changeHandle = (e) => {
    setMovie((m) => e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    movieName(movie);
    setMovie("");
  };

  return (
    <form style={containerStyle} className="movieForm" onSubmit={submitHandle}>
      <h1 style={h1Style}>DownTime</h1>

      <input
        style={inputStyle}
        type="text"
        value={movie}
        onChange={changeHandle}
        placeholder="Search a movie.."
      />
      <button
        onClick={submitHandle}
        variant="contained"
        className="buttonStyle"
        style={buttonStyle}
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```css
.movieCard {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  color: white;
  /*margin-left:750px;
   margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 70px;*/
}

.stylemovie3 {
  color: yellowgreen;
}

.cardContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.layover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 370px;
  left: 0px;*/
  top: 349px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* Semi-transparent white background */
  padding: 20px; /* Add padding for content inside the layover */
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure the layover appears above other elements */
}

.buttonStyle {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 2px solid white; /* Border color */
  outline: none;
  /*background-color: #666; /* Button color */
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition on hover */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.myButton1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px; /* Adjust padding to change button size */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid white; /* Border color */
  border-radius: 15px; /* Rounded corners */
  background-color: #333; /* Button color */
  color: #fff; /* Text color */
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition on hover */
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.myButton2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px; /* Adjust padding to change button size */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid white; /* Border color */
  border-radius: 15px; /* Rounded corners */
  background-color: #333; /* Button color */
  color: #fff; /* Text color */
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition on hover */
  position: relative;
  right: 110px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.myButton1:hover:hover,
.myButton2:hover:hover,
.buttonStyle:hover {
  background-color: #333; /* Darker shade on hover */
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Styles for small screens, such as mobile phones in portrait mode */
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  .buttonStyle {
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .movieCard {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .myButton1 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .myButton2 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: -90px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, as well as any debugging observations you have made.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: didn't think my code was relevant cuz idk I feel like the problem is with me not knowing how to style react to be responsive for all screen sizes how i dont with html/css/js file which is so simple

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating another component  for movieForm with its unique style so  and with js conditioning I alternated between both
so separating style was my solution to this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).